# Identity.getCredentials throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, seam, code-injection

I'm working on the front-end of a web application developed using JBoss seam. I'm encountering a `NullPointerException` at user login but I don't know how it happens. Here's a summary based from the log.

When a user tries to login, the authenticate method in the LoginBean was executed

```
    public class LoginBean{
            //both from org.jboss.seam.security package
            @In
            private Credentials credentials

            @In
            private Identity identity

            public boolean authenticate(){
                    ...

                    //false
                    logger.info(identity.getCredential null? == " + identity.getCredential==null);

                    //this returns true
                    result = webAuthentication.login(credential.getUsername(), credential.getPassword());

                    return result;
            }
    }
```

I can still access the credentials attribute of the identity object in this code. After executing the authenticate, the log shows that a method from another class was executed.

```
    public class LoginControllerBean{
            @In 
            private Identity identity; //org.jboss.seam.security

            @Observer("org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful")
            @Begin(join = true)
            public void updateSessionUserStats(){
                    //i can still see this in the log
                    logger.info("Login successful. updating sessionUserInfo....");

                    //throws NullPointerException  
                    logger.info("check identity.getCredential if null == " + identity.getCredential());


                    sessionUser = new SessionUser();
                    //if I remove the log above this call will throw NullPointerException                        
                    sessionUser.setUsername(identity.getCredentials().getUsername());
            }

    }
```

I assumed that the login was successful because the method with the `@Observer(...loginSuccessful)` annotation was executed right after authenticate.

Both of the identity objects in the first and second class are injected by `@In annotation.`
Why is the `identity.getCredentials() throws nullPointerException` on the second code while it is ok on the first code? What could be the cause of i`dentity.getCredentials() throwing nullPointerException?` Sorry if I cannot give more details on the problem. I can only access the front-end codes.Thanks.

Comment: identity is null so you got the nullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure to get a non null use

```
  @In(create=true)
    private Identity identity
```